# How to create Heat Distortion Shockwave for explosion?

Tags: animation, particles, physics, fire

I have seen a number of tutorials on Shockwaves and they all look cartoonish to me. I have seen a tutorial by Andrew Price and another one using a plane and a refraction texture animated with noise to create just the heat distortion over a fixed object. What I am trying to create is the expanding blast wave of distortion associated with concussion from exploding munitions in a realistic way.

I have thought about animating donut ring and applying a refraction material so that the ring expands with the explosion. I don't think this will work for my needs since in this case the explosion occurs inside.

I have thought about doing a particle simulation with an exploding blast of particles that only have a refraction material assigned to them.

I'd like to try and create a blast similar to this, created in this Fracture Fx for Maya demo. I can't seem to find an external URL outside of facebook for this video as it wasn't on their website but here:
https://www.facebook.com/FractureFX/videos/705143703272645/

Comment: This is a good question, and I hope someone will offer a good, detailed tutorial-type answer. You can see these shockwaves in the air emanating from [real explosions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6ukz5jhXdY) there's a quasi-spherical shape that expands from the blast center through the air, distorting the background, and this interacts with the ground, kicking up dust in an expanding ring along the ground.